# php mysql check previous row

Tags: php, mysql

I have output from a select query as below

```
id          price  valid    
1000368     69.95   1       
1000369     69.94   0       
1000370     69.95   0
```

now in php I am trying to pass the id 1000369 in function. the funciton can execute only if the valid =1 for id 1000368. if it's not 1 then it will throw error. so if the id passed is 1000370, it will check if valid =1 for 1000369.

how can i check this? I think it is logically possible to do but I am not able to code it i tried using foreach but at the end it always checks the last record 1000370 and so it throws error.

regards

Comment: What function? Please show your code so we have a point of reference.

Comment: This is some basic stuff here. I am glad you are seeking help but please read some basic tutorials too.

Comment: why someone would give a -ve vote? is there anything like good/bad question one can ask here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a boolean variable:

```
<?php
$lastValid=false;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($lastValid) {
        myFunction();
    }
    $lastValid = $row['valid'];
}
?>
```

(Excuse possible errors, have no access to a console at the moment.)

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply..can you please explain me, how setting the $lastvalid = false is possible? I thought I should check if row[valid] = 1 in the if condition..

Comment: While the above code should work, you could just start off with `$lastvalid=0`, which would make a bit more sense. The reason is that PHP considers `0` to be equal to `false`, and any other number to be `true` (that idea is borrowed from the C programming language). So `if ($lastValid)` (which is a short way of saying `if ($lastValid==true)`) is the same as saying `if ($lastValid != 0)`

Comment: thank you. I got it right. I had to include "break" after $lastValid = $row['valid'];
 so that it doesn't do for the first record.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to check the if the previous id is `valid`.

```
$prev['valid'] = 0;

foreach($input as $i){

    if($prev['valid']){

        // Execute function

    }

    $prev = $i;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$qry = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
    if ($row['valid'] == 1)
    {
        // do some actions
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really really recommend walking through some tutorials. This is basic stuff man.

Here is how to request a specific record:

```
//This is to inspect a specific record
$id = '1000369'; //**some specified value**
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data_tbl WHERE id = $id";
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));

$valid = $data['valid'];

if ($valid == 1)
  //Do this
else
  //Do that
```

And here is how to loop through all the records and check each.

```
//This is to loop through all of it.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data_tbl";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$previous_row = null;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
  some_action($row, $previous_row);
  $previous_row = $row; //At the end of the call the current row becomes the previous one. This way you can refer to it in the next iteration through the loop
}

function some_action($data, $previous_data)
{
  if (!empty($previous_data) && $condition_is_met)
  {
    //Use previous data
    $valid = $previous_data['valid'];
  }
  else
  {
    //Use data
    $valid = $data['valid'];
  }

  if ($valid == 1)
  {
    //Do the valid thing
  }
  else
  {
    //Do the not valid thing
  }

  //Do whatever
}
```

Here are some links to some good tutorials:
http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorials
http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php